# How to add a div after a div that containing two floating divs inside?

Tags: floating, html

I have 5 divs, named Header,A,B,C,D. B and C are floating divs inside A. I put a  after C.
I have a problem with D (a kind of footer) when B has very long text content.
D seems to stay just behind Header and behind B like z-index lower.
Here is the live site: http://dkm.org.tr/proje/biyolojik-cesitliligin-ormanciliga-entegrasyonu-projesi.html

Thank you.
Ç.

Comment: and another sample page: http://dkm.org.tr/hakkimizda

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use the *clear* property after the floating elements.

```
clear: both;
```

For example:

```
<div style="float:left;">B...</div>
<div style="float:left;">C...</div>
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
```

This should solve your problem